# How to add a sequential animation on an imageview to scale up and scale down repeatedly in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, animation

I am trying to do an animation on an imageview, were i need to scale up and scale down the image so that it will have a shadow feel effect for another animation.

I tried adding two xml in anim folder -

scale_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:duration="1250"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.5" />

</set>
```

scale_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:duration="1250"
        android:fromXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

and in my activity class

```
AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);
View shadowView = view.findViewById(R.id.shadowView);
final Animation scaleDownAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,   R.anim.scale_down);
final Animation scaleUpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,   R.anim.scale_up);
s.addAnimation(scaleUpAnimation);
s.addAnimation(scaleDownAnimation);
shadowView.startAnimation(s);
```

But animation is not happening. What i am doing wrong? Anyone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`AnimationSet` performs animation **simultanuously**, not **sequentaly** by default. So it does zoom in and zoom out at the same time. That's why you see no effect. But you can set a start offset to the animation:

```
AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);
View shadowView = view.findViewById(R.id.shadowView);
final Animation scaleDownAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,   R.anim.scale_down);
final Animation scaleUpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,   R.anim.scale_up);
scaleDownAnimation.setStartOffset(1250); //this line
s.addAnimation(scaleUpAnimation);
s.addAnimation(scaleDownAnimation);
shadowView.startAnimation(s
```

Comment: I have already tried adding the same in xml android:startOffset="1250", but then the animation is having a jerk in between

Comment: @BibinVelayudhan, you should have mentioned it in question. And that is another problem actually. You also can just set listener to the first animation, and start second animation when listener tells you that first one finished.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. But using xml we cant do a sequential animation?

Comment: @BibinVelayudhan, we can - the way that you don't like, by setting startOffset. It should not have any jerks in between. You can try setting offset to some lower value, like 1200 instead of 1250 to elliminate jerk